# My javascript isn't working on the login page only refreshes?

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, login-script

At first it worked but then it stopped working can't find the error please help!
When you write in the correct username and password it only puts it in the url and doesn't work.
The demo version has css ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
[DEMO](https://zany-leo.glitch.me/) <----------------------------------------------------------------

```js
/*This Script allows people to enter by using a form that asks for a
UserID and Password*/
function pasuser(form) {
if (form.identifier.value=="GG") { 
if (form.pass.value=="123") { 
  window.location('https://www.google.com/');
} else {
alert("Invalid Password");
}

} else {  alert("Invalid UserID");
}
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
  <script src="/server.js"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form>
      <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="text" name="identifier" required="">
        <label>Username</label>
      </div>
      <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="password" name="pass" required="">
        <label>Password</label>
      </div>
      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="pasuser(form)">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code you're showing and the code in your demo are two different things.  The code you're showing produces a very clear error message when you run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

window.location is not a function.  try window.location.assign(.....

```js
/*This Script allows people to enter by using a form that asks for a
UserID and Password*/
function pasuser(form) {
if (form.identifier.value=="GG") { 
console.log(form.identifier.value)
if (form.pass.value=="123") { 
  window.location.assign('https://www.google.com/');
} else {
alert("Invalid Password");
}

} else {  alert("Invalid UserID");
}
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
  <script src="/server.js"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form>
      <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="text" name="identifier" required="">
        <label>Username</label>
      </div>
      <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="password" name="pass" required="">
        <label>Password</label>
      </div>
      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="pasuser(form)">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```